# How can I execute non-query Stored Procedure in JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a stored procedure in a postgres database. I'm using the postgres JDBC driver to execute a stored procedure, and I do not care about the return type, and can't execute the query. It's indicating that there's a syntax error near the name of the function.

In procedures that return rows, I've been able to do this via a PreparedStatement and setting the parameters, like:

```
PreparedStatement prepared = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM NonQueryProcedure(?)");
prepared.setInt(1, 999);
// ....
ResulSet resultSet = prepared.executeQuery();
```

However, I can't seem to get this to work for an "update" stored procedure where I don't care about the return type. I've tried using connection.prepareStatement() and prepareCall(), and also tried executing it with statement.execute(), .executeUpdate(), and .executeQuery(), without success.

How can I execute a stored procedure where I don't care about the return type?

Comment: `.execute()` should do the trick. Perhaps your SQL isn't valid. Can we see?

Comment: I've run the procedure via the postgres shell with success. Are you suggesting using .execute() with a .prepareStatement()?

statement = connection.prepareStatement("nonQueryProcedure1(?)");
statement.execute();. doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like it works if I created the prepared statement as:
PreparedStatement prepared = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT nonQueryProcedure1(?)");

Had to do that on the command line as well. Not sure why though. Not familiar with that SQL syntax. perhaps it is postgres specific?

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't have stored procedures as such, only functions. Going the `{call nonQueryProcedure1 ? }` route might automatically wrap that in a SELECT to perform it as if it was one, not sure.

Comment: Just use `execute("select NonQueryProcedure(?)");`

Comment: You should certainly use prepareCall() for stored procedures.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name your comment is correct. Do you want to post it as an answer so I can close this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As PostgreSQL has no "real" procedures, functions are simply executed using a `SELECT` statement:

```
statement.execute("select NonQueryProcedure(?)");
```

Note that inside a PL/pgSQL function, you can use the [`perform`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT) statement to call such a function. But this is not available outside of a PL/pgSQL block.

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual syntax error, I can't say for sure, but try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM \"getData\"(?)"
```

CamelCase/PascalCase is a BAD idea in any SQL database. Either it folds it to a single case and all you see is AMASSOFUNREADABLELETTERS or it requires quoting and you will have to forevermore type "aMassofLettersAndQuotesAndShiftKeysAndMyFingersHurt" anytime you want to avoid a syntax error.